# R plotly subplot warning 'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'NA'

Tags: r, plotly, warnings, r-plotly

I am trying to combine a two plotly figures (`type = 'mesh3d'` and `type = 'scatter3d'`). Each of the single plots is perfectly fine without any warning. After I use `subplot` a warning occurs every time I try to display the plot.

*warning 'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'NA'*

I have tried to `suppressWarning` but this does not have any effect.

Any ideas what I am missing here to get rid of the warning?

Plotly Version: 4.9.3
R Version: 4.0.1

```
# plot data
plt_data <- data.frame(maturity=rep(1:10, each=10),
                   tenor=rep(1:10, 10),
                   value=rnorm(100))

# plot 1
fig11 <- plot_ly(
           data=plt_data, x=~maturity, y=~tenor, z = ~value,
           type = "mesh3d",intensity = ~value,
           colors = colorRamp(c(
              rgb(168, 191, 173, max = 255),
              rgb(100, 181, 117, max = 255),
              rgb(0,100,80, max = 255)
           )),
           contour=list(show=T, width=4, color="#fff"),
           showscale = F,
           scene='scene1', 
           lighting = list(ambient = 0.9),
           hoverinfo="skip",
           source="myID"
) 


# plot 2
fig12 <- plot_ly(
           data=plt_data, x=~maturity, y=~tenor, z = ~value,
           type = "scatter3d",
           mode="markers",
           hovertemplate="Maturity: %{x:.f}<br>Tenor: %{y:.f}<br>Value: %{z:.4f}<extra></extra>",
           marker=list(
             symbol="square-open",
             size=4,
             color="#3d543f"
           ),
           scene='scene1',
           source="myID",showlegend=F
) 

# subplot which does throw a warning
subplot(fig11, fig12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/994) regarding the warning. Here's a workaround to hide the warnings for this case -

```
function_to_hide_plotly_warning <- function(...) {
  plot <- subplot(...)
  plot$x$layout <- plot$x$layout[grep('NA', names(plot$x$layout), invert = TRUE)]
  plot
}

function_to_hide_plotly_warning(fig11, fig12)
```

Comment: I found this open issue, but can't translate it into R. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

For R and Shinyapps, to suppress warnings like this:

`options(warn = -1)`